# jQuery ajax promise with finally

Tags: jquery, typescript, rest, promise, finally

I am trying to access a REST api using jQuery's `ajax` functionality.

What I want to do is return the `Promise<Customer>` object, but I get the error, that the property `finally` is missing. It did work in past, so I guess there have been some changes lately. I just cannot find out how to provide the missing `finally` property.

I guess there has to be an easy fix, but yet it wasn't easy to find any solution on the net.

The failing class:

```
export class ServiceCustomer {
    public requestCustomers(): Promise<Customer> {
        const dataString: ResourceParamCustomer = {
            something: 'some entry',
            nextthing: 'other entry',
        };

        return $.ajax({
            contentType: 'application/json',
            data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/customer/list',
        });;
    }
}
```

The error:

```
ERROR in [at-loader] ./src/Service/ServiceCustomer.ts:12:15 
    TS2741: Property 'finally' is missing in type 'jqXHR<any>' but required in type 'Promise<Customer>'.
```

Relevant entries in the `package.json`:

```
{
    ...
    "dependencies": {
        ...
        "@types/jquery": "3.3.31",
        ...
        "jquery": "3.4.1",
        "popper.js": "1.16.0",
        ...
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "9.7.1",
        "awesome-typescript-loader": "5.2.1",
        "clean-webpack-plugin": "3.0.0",
        ...
        "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
        ...
        "tslint": "5.20.1",
        "typescript": "3.7.2",
        "typings-for-css-modules-loader": "1.7.0",
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

The tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./dist/",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2015",
        "jsx": "react",
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Comment: (1) jQuery Deferreds/Promises have an [`.always()`](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) method, not `.finally()`.
(2) `.finally()` doesn't appear in the code posted.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 `.always()` is kind of like `.finally()`, because both execute on both success and error. Is there a way to connect them to be able to return the promise as posted? How would I provide the needed `finally` parameter?

Comment: Either you are working with jQuery promises (with .always) or JS native promises (with .finally). You *can* cast a jQuery promise as native, but (a) you must do so intelligently as jQuery spreads its data, and (b) it's hardly worthwhile just to make .finally available when you already have .always.

Answer (score 1):

The `jQuery` `ajax` promise does not have a `finally` method.  Therefore, it is not compatible with TypeScript `Promise` definition.

The `ajax` promise is type compatible with the TypeScript `PromiseLike` definition because it implements a `then` callback.  However, the `ajax` promise is functionally different in that the callbacks have multiple parameters as documented [jQuery ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

```js
jqXHR.then(
    function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {},
    function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {}
);
```

You can convert the jQuery promise into a native Promise by creating a `Promise` object like the following.

```
export class ServiceCustomer {
    public requestCustomers(): Promise<Customer> {
        const dataString: ResourceParamCustomer = {
            something: 'some entry',
            nextthing: 'other entry',
        };

        return new Promise<Customer>((resolve, reject) => {
            $.ajax<Customer>({
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(dataString),
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/customer/list',
            }).then(
                (data, textStatus, jqXHR) => {
                    resolve(data);
                },
                (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
                    const error = createError(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
                    reject(error);
                }
            );
        });
    }
}
```